# one way anova to compare each factor against the mean

Tags: probability, anova

I have a factor with six levels and then a proportion for each of those levels. I have six months that women became pregnant and then the proportion who smoked during pregnancy, as an example.

I used an anova and I know that there are significant differences in the group.

I also used a tukey hsd and I looked at the pair-wise differences.

I simply want to know if the difference in each factor is significant against the average for everyone.

Is that something I can learn with a one way anova?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be using a binary regression model (e.g., logistic regression) to get correct inferences. ANOVA is designed for continuous outcomes (not binary), and the standard errors and p-values will only be correct under normally distributed outcomes. You can continue to use ANOVA with binary data as long as you use a robust standard error.

There is a way to code the categorical variable so that the interpretation of the intercept is the mean of the outcomes across the categories (i.e., the grand mean) and the interpretation of each slope is the deviation of each category from the grand mean. This is called deviation or effect coding. In R this can be done using the `contr.sum` function. For example, you might run the following:

```
fit <- glm(smoke ~ month, data = data, 
           family = binomial(link = "identity"),
           contrasts = list(month = contr.sum))
jtools::summ(fit, robust = TRUE, digits = 3)
```

(Ignore the warning you'll get about `month` being absent.)

Unfortunately the R output is a little ambiguous and you'll have to do some work do determine which coefficient belongs to which group. You can easily check the probabilities for each group using

```
(smoke_by_month <- with(data, tapply(smoke, month, mean)))
```

and then assess which coefficients correspond to which groups.

One caution is that you won't get a test for one of the months. This is because the result of this test is not independent from the results of the other tests. You can manually calculate the deviations from the grand mean (e.g., with `smoke_by_month - mean(smoke_by_month)`), but you won't get a hypothesis test for this group. If you want a hypothesis test for this group, `relevel` the month factor and run the analysis again.

Comment: When I relevel the month factor for the test against the grand mean, would you recommend that I relevel it so that it includes everything, except the chosen month as one factor and my chosen month as the other?

Comment: It doesn't matter. In your first model, one of the months will be absent in the output. If you relevel the factor in any way that is different, that month will appear.

Comment: @Noah: For a "binary logistic regression model", the outcome variable should be a binary variable (e.g., 1 if a woman smoked, 0 if the woman did not smoke). It seems that the asker of the question has aggregated responses (e.g., proportion of smokers among pregnant women).

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I assumed they had individual-level data on when each woman smoked and what month each woman got pregnant. They described comparing proportions the same way some describe comparing means. To use ANOVA and pairwise differences, you need individual-level data, so I made that assumption from the context.

Comment: @Noah:  The original post is a bit confusing.  For example, why would the asker of the question perform multiple pairwise comparisons when they are interested in comparing the mean response for each factor level against the average response across all factor levels.  Also, using ANOVA for a response variable expressed as a proportion can be problematic.  So I think we would need further clarifications from Cauder to understand what it is that is being modelled here.

Comment: Noah's description is right.